# Is $g$ increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, advice

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and define $g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as follows
>   $$
> g(x)=\sup\{f(t):a\leq t\leq x\},
> $$
>   with $x\in[a,b]$.

Someone told me that $g$ is an increasing function, but I don't see it. I don't see, how in the case of $g$, $\forall y_1,y_2\in[a,b]$, $$y_1\leq y_2 \rightarrow g(y_1)\leq g(y_2).$$

Please help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: This follows from "If $A \subseteq B$ then $\sup(A) \le \sup(B)$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is increasing (not necessarily strictly) because you are taking supremum over an increasingly bigger set.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Wouldn't $f$ also have to be increasing?

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.